# Kubent Plugin with Calico Network Policy

Tags: azure-aks, calico

I have created an AKS Cluster with the Kubenet plugin and Calico Network Policy.
I wanted to know whether I should consider Calico and its components as part of the managed AKS experience, or I should take care of updating it?
I wasn't able to find this info in the AKS docs.

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AKS takes care of it. Even if you upgrade the version, AKS will reconcile and downgrade it to the version they currently support.
source : https://academy.tigera.io/course/certified-calico-operator-azure-expert/